# To draw two arrows to one point

Tags: arrows, tikz-arrows

I want pictures where I can point by two arrows with labels to one point like here

[image]

**How can you have two arrows pointing to one point?**

Comment: Sorry to bother you, but rereading you question I wonder to which two arrows are you referring to. Are you talking about the two arrows that end in "MHC II cl."? I ask you because I'm not sure if my answer below was what you were looking for.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks for accepting the answer; please do not think I was pressing you to do so, I was only asking to see if there was something missing in the answer :) If you agree, we can delete our comments so as to tidy up a bit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf) and a basic `\node`s construct:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
mynode/.style={
  font=\color{blue}
  },
ar/.style={->,>=latex,line width=2pt,green!70!black}
]
\node[mynode] (ag) {Ag};
\node[mynode,right=of ag] (atc) {ATC};
\node[mynode,right=of atc] (mhc) {MHC II cl.};
\node[mynode,right=of mhc] (tly) {T\,ly};
\node[mynode,right=of tly] (bly) {B\,ly};
\node[mynode,below=of atc] (sta) {Staphylococcus};

\draw[ar] (ag) -- (atc);
\draw[ar] (atc) -- (mhc);
\draw[ar] (mhc) -- (tly);
\draw[ar] (tly) -- coordinate (aux) (bly);

\node[mynode] (cyt) at (aux|-sta) {Cytokins};

\draw[ar] (sta) -- (mhc);
\draw[ar,shorten <= 5pt] (aux) -- (cyt);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option would be to use chains. Please refer to the PGF manual.